# Telerik MVC tabstrip ToString fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have the following issue with a Telerik component (tabstrip).

I have a HTML extension method that renders something on the page. Code portion:

```
var tabstrip = Html.EagleTabstrip()
                        .Name(Container.GroupName)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "icon-listbox-wrapper" } })
                        .Items(items =>
                        {
                            bool isFirst = true;
                            foreach (SomeClass widget in Widgets)
                            {
                                items.Add()
                                    .Selected(isFirst)
                                    .Text(widget.GroupName??"").Content(Html.RenderResourceWidgetContainer(widget).ToString() /*This call is recursive, the function has an if block just above*/);

                                isFirst = false;
                            }
                        });
                    var mvcHTMLString = MvcHtmlString.Create(tabstrip.ToString());
                    return mvcHTMLString;
```

The ToString() call, however, fails with a very stupid(IMO) error message: Sequence contains no matching element.

Where/what am I doing wrong? Any additional info will be provided upon requirement, so feel free to bomb me with questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the ToString() call on the tabstrip? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Extension method header: `public static MvcHtmlString RenderResourceWidgetContainer(this HtmlHelper Html, ResourceWidgetContainerModel Container)` The return type must be MvcHtmlString, since I don't always generate a tabstrip, hence the recursiveness :)

Comment: Wait, maybe I understood this wrong: is it the tabstrip.ToString() call that throws the error message or the RenderResourceWidgetContainer(widget).ToString() ?

Comment: The tabstrip.ToString() call